# $C(G) \otimes C(G) \simeq C(G \times G)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, quantum-groups

Let be $G$ a compact group and $C(G)$ the vector space of continue complex functions defined over $G$, $C(G):=\{f:G \to \mathbb{C}\}$, where $f$ is a continue function. How can I prove that 
$$ C(G) \otimes C(G) \simeq C(G \times G) ?$$

Comment: Is your goal simply that they are isomorphic as vector spaces (for which it is enough to show that they have Hamel bases of the same cardinality), or something nicer?

Comment: Consider the map $f\otimes g\mapsto h$ where $h(x,y) = f(x)g(y)$.

Comment: Is this an ordinary tensor product, or a Banach space tensor product of some sort (by suitable completion of an ordinary tensor product)? I'm reasonably sure an ordinary tensor product wouldn't work.

Comment: @user43208 Why the ordinary tensor product doesn't work?

Comment: @HenningMakholm I have to prove they are isomorphic as vector space... How can I do it? Is there e way to prove the isomorphism as Banach algebras?

Comment: As Henning points out, if you want a (non-canonical) vector space isomorphism, all you need to do is show that both sides have Hamel bases (ordinary vector space bases) of the same cardinality. If an infinite $\kappa$ is the minimum over all cardinalities of dense subsets of $G$, then a Hamel basis of $C(G)$ has size $2^\kappa$. So do $C(G) \otimes C(G)$ and $C(G \times G)$. Of course, this observation is useless for any serious purpose: the induced vector space isomorphism will be wildly discontinuous. I expect you'd be more interested in a canonical isomorphism, and for that, see my answer.

Answer (score 4):

In general, if it is the ordinary vector space tensor product we are talking about, the canonical map $C(G) \otimes C(G) \to C(G \times G)$ that takes $\phi \otimes \psi$ to the function $(g, h) \mapsto \phi(g)\psi(h)$ is not an isomorphism. It does however give an isomorphism onto a dense subspace of $C(G \times G)$ (equipped as usual with the topology of uniform convergence, given by the sup norm). None of this depends on the group structure of $G$, incidentally.

This is not a subject I am intimately acquainted with (I am a category theorist, not a specialist in Banach space theory or TVS theory), but some useful information can be gleaned from this [online text](http://www2.math.uni-paderborn.de/fileadmin/Mathematik/People/kbierstedt/01-Manuskripte/Bierstedt_TopologicalTensorproducts.pdf). Proposition 5.29 (page 35) seems to be the result most directly relevant to the OP. In brief, for compact (Hausdorff) spaces $K, K'$, the Banach space $C(K \times K')$ is isomorphic to the [injective tensor product](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/tensor+product+of+Banach+spaces) $C(K) \otimes_\varepsilon C(K')$ of the Banach spaces $C(K)$, $C(K')$. As for how the ordinary tensor product of vector spaces figures in, there is a canonical isomorphism $C(K \times K') \cong C(K, C(K'))$, and what we can say is that image of the composite

$$C(K) \otimes C(K') \to C(K \times K') \cong C(K, C(K'))$$

is the subspace consisting of continuous functions $K \to C(K')$ with finite-dimensional image (in the infinite-dimensional Banach space $C(K')$). See example 1.11 (page 8); see also example 1.13 for the density statement.

Once all this is squared away, then one can begin contemplating how the group structure on $G$ manifests itself. Undoubtedly one will have a Banach space version of a Hopf algebra structure on $C(G)$, notably involving a comultiplication

$$\delta: C(G) \to C(G) \otimes_\varepsilon C(G)$$

that is a Banach algebra map. But this is beyond the scope of the actual question.